# AutoMapper -- inheritance mapping not working, same source, multiple destinations

Tags: c#, inheritance, automapper, automapper-2

Can I use inheritance mapping in AutoMapper (v2.2) for maps with the same Source type but different Destination types?

I have this basic situation (the real classes have many more properties):

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel
{
    public int CommonProperty { get; set;}
}

public class ViewModelA : BaseViewModel
{
    public int PropertyA { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModelB : BaseViewModel
{
    public int PropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

`ViewModelA` and `ViewModelB` are different representations of the same Entity class:

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public int Property2 { get; set; }
    public int Property3 { get; set; }
}
```

I want to reuse the same mapping for `BaseViewModel` for each ViewModel, such as:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Entity, BaseViewModel>()
    .Include<Entity, ViewModelA>()
    .Include<Entity, ViewModelB>()
    .ForMember(x => x.CommonProperty, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.Property1));

Mapper.CreateMap<Entity, ViewModelA>()
    .ForMember(x => x.PropertyA, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.Property2));

Mapper.CreateMap<Entity, ViewModelB>()
    .ForMember(x => x.PropertyB, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.Property3));
```

But unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work.  Calls like these:

```
var model = Mapper.Map<Entity, ViewModelA>(entity);
```

result in `model` having `PropertyA` mapped, but not `CommonProperty`.  I believe I'm following the examples in https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Mapping-inheritance properly, but I'm afraid having multiple maps created with the same Source type is tripping AutoMapper up.

Any insights?  I love the idea of grouping Base class mappings together, but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: For future readers of this question - it appears AutoMapper has fixed this since the question was asked.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing here, but I'm trying to do:

`var model = Mapper.Map<Entity, BaseViewModel>(entity)`

but it's returning an instance of ViewModelA, not an instance of BaseViewModel, even thought I'm telling the Map function to return a BaseViewModel type. I'm using Automapper 3.0 so, it seems like the original bug from 2.2 has been resolved.

Comment: This SO post helped me with my issue and got the desired effect to work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27317719/automapper-how-to-not-repeat-mapping-config-from-complex-type-to-base-class

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately in this case, AutoMapper seems to be registering only one child class mapping per source type, the last one (`ViewModelB`). This was probably designed to work with parallel hierarchies, not with a single source type.

To work around this, you can encapsulate the common mappings in an extension method:

```
public static IMappingExpression<Entity, TDestination> MapBaseViewModel<TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<Entity, TDestination> map)
  where TDestination : BaseViewModel { 
  return map.ForMember(x => x.CommonProperty, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.Property1));
}
```

And use it in the individual subclass mappings:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Entity, ViewModelA>()
  .MapBaseViewModel<ViewModelA>()
  .ForMember(x => x.PropertyA, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.Property2));

Mapper.CreateMap<Entity, ViewModelB>()
  .MapBaseViewModel<ViewModelB>()
  .ForMember(x => x.PropertyB, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.Property3));
```

Comment: Thanks but not worked for me. Could you please have a look at [Using AutoMapper to map Base Classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39425775/using-automapper-to-map-base-classes) question?

Answer (score 1):

Yo can do like here

```
            CreateMap<Entity, ViewModelA>()
            .InheritMapping(x =>
            {
                x.IncludeDestinationBase<BaseViewModel>();
            });
```

There is  code of extension

```
public static class MapExtensions
{        

    public static void InheritMapping<TSource, TDestination>(
        this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> mappingExpression,
        Action<InheritMappingExpresssion<TSource, TDestination>> action)
    {
        InheritMappingExpresssion<TSource, TDestination> x =
            new InheritMappingExpresssion<TSource, TDestination>(mappingExpression);
        action(x);
        x.ConditionsForAll();
    }

    private static bool NotAlreadyMapped(Type sourceType, Type desitnationType, ResolutionContext r, Type typeSourceCurrent, Type typeDestCurrent)
    {
        var result = !r.IsSourceValueNull &&
               Mapper.FindTypeMapFor(sourceType, desitnationType).GetPropertyMaps().Where(
                   m => m.DestinationProperty.Name.Equals(r.MemberName)).Select(y => !y.IsMapped()
                   ).All(b => b);
        return result;
    }
    public class InheritMappingExpresssion<TSource, TDestination>
    {
        private readonly IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> _sourcExpression;
        public InheritMappingExpresssion(IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> sourcExpression)
        {
            _sourcExpression = sourcExpression;
        }
        public void IncludeSourceBase<TSourceBase>(
            bool ovverideExist = false)
        {
            Type sourceType = typeof (TSourceBase);
            Type destinationType = typeof (TDestination);
            if (!sourceType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof (TSource))) throw new NotSupportedException();
            Result(sourceType, destinationType);
        }
        public void IncludeDestinationBase<TDestinationBase>()
        {
            Type sourceType = typeof (TSource);
            Type destinationType = typeof (TDestinationBase);
            if (!destinationType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof (TDestination))) throw new NotSupportedException();
            Result(sourceType, destinationType);
        }
        public void IncludeBothBases<TSourceBase, TDestinatioBase>()
        {
            Type sourceType = typeof (TSourceBase);
            Type destinationType = typeof (TDestinatioBase);
            if (!sourceType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof (TSource))) throw new NotSupportedException();
            if (!destinationType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof (TDestination))) throw new NotSupportedException();
            Result(sourceType, destinationType);
        }
        internal void ConditionsForAll()
        {
            _sourcExpression.ForAllMembers(x => x.Condition(r => _conditions.All(c => c(r))));//указываем что все кондишены истинны
        }
        private List<Func<ResolutionContext, bool>> _conditions = new List<Func<ResolutionContext, bool>>();
        private void Result(Type typeSource, Type typeDest)
        {
                _sourcExpression.BeforeMap((x, y) =>
                {
                    Mapper.Map(x, y, typeSource, typeDest);
                });
                _conditions.Add((r) => NotAlreadyMapped(typeSource, typeDest, r, typeof (TSource), typeof (TDestination)));
        }
    }

}
```