# Automapper: Only first Include works

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a really strange problem, which I can't explain. See this Map for an AutomapperProfile:

```
            CreateMap<BO, AbstractDto>()
            .Include<BO, ConcreteDto1>()
            .Include<BO, ConcreteDto2>()
            .ForMember(d...));
```

I have the same Business-Object and one abstract Dto with two concrete implementations.
If I just use this, the AutoMapper only recognizes the first Include, but ignores the second one and throws an exception.
I verified this by first including the ConcreteDto2, which caused this mapping to work and the ConcreteDto1 to throw.

The closest answer I found was: 
[AutoMapper -- inheritance mapping not working, same source, multiple destinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994081/automapper-inheritance-mapping-not-working-same-source-multiple-destination) but in my case it definitely only takes the first Include.

Is this the same problem as in the Thread, or is there another problem? If yes so, is there a convinient solution arround without code duplicating?

Thanks in advance

Matthias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in AutoMapper 4.0, with a PR open to fix it for 4.1. For now, you need to use `Mapper.Initialize` instead of `Mapper.CreateMap` to perform initial configuration.